# Spring IntegrationFlow Filter and Transform

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-integration

I have some XML that I am trying to get through an Integration Flow.  Here are the steps that I'm doing:

- Filter out the message if it contains the XML node: "filterMe" AND has type = "filterType" - If so, I dont want to process it.
- Transform it from XML to a Kotlin class, and add some headers to the message.

I cant find a way to properly filter the message on 2 XML properties.  Any help very much appreciated.

Here is some example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response type="filterType">//Filter on this
   <event>
      <header>
         <type>Test</type>
      </header>
      <body>
         <filterMe>filter me out</filterMe> //Filter this too
      </body>
   </event>
</Response>
```

Integration Flow

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(inputChannel)
                .filter("filterMe"::contains)
                .transform { payload: String ->
                    val jsonMessage = XML.toJSONObject(payload).toString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to lean [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

With Spring Integration in the `filter()` you can do like this:

```
.filter(payload -> 
                XPathUtils.evaluate(payload, "/Response/@type = \"filterType\" and //filterMe", 
                                    XPathUtils.BOOLEAN))
```

Note: you should have `spring-integration-xml` in classpath to get access to that `XPathUtils`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great.  I also learned quite a bit about x path, so thanks for that too.